# Parsing XML which contains illegal characters

Tags: c#, xml

A message I receive from a server contains tags and in the tags is the data I need.

I try to parse the payload as *XML* but illegal character exceptions are generated.

I also made use of `httpUtility` and `Security Utility` to escape the illegal characters, only problem is, it will escape `< >` which is needed to parse the *XML*.

My question is, how do I parse *XML* when the data contained in it contains illegal non *XML* characters? `(& -> amp;)`_

Thanks.

Example:

```
<item><code>1234</code><title>voi hoody & polo shirt + Mckenzie jumper</title><description>Good condition size small - medium, text me if interested</description></item>
```

Comment: You have malformed XML document. Server must send proper data. If it is possible try to fix server side. The description must be `CDATA`.

Comment: Seeing as what you're trying to parse isn't XML, you're going to have to do something non-standard to address the problem. I'd go with getting the source fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot do anything with regards to the server.

I am trying to get round the idea of creating my own custom reader.

I thought I could cheat by using XML and was wondering if anyone knew a way around the above problem.

If not it looks like I will have to create my own custom reader.

i.e. read between the tags reader

Comment: you could try `string.Replace()` method to fix all the illegals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only `&` as invalid character, then you can use regex to replace it with `&amp;`. We use regex to prevent replacement of already existing `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&#111;`, etc. symbols.

Regex can be as follows:

```
&(?!(?:lt|gt|amp|apos|quot|#\d+|#x[a-f\d]+);)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
string content = @"<item><code>1234 &amp; test</code><title>voi hoody & polo shirt + Mckenzie jumper&other stuff</title><description>Good condition size small - medium, text me if interested</description></item>";
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"&(?!(?:lt|gt|amp|apos|quot|#\d+|#x[a-f\d]+);)", "&amp;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
XElement xItem = XElement.Parse(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call it "XML which contains illegal characters". It isn't XML. You can't use XML tools to process something that isn't XML.

When you get bad XML, the best thing is to find out where and when it was generated, and fix the problem at source.

If you can't do that, you need to find some way using non-XML tools (e.g. custom perl scripts) to repair the XML before you let it anywhere near an XML parser. The way you do this will depend on the nature of the errors you need to repair.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more generalized solution than `Regex`. First declare an array, store each invalid character that you want to replace with encoded version into it:

```
var invalidChars = new [] { '&', other chars comes here.. };
```

Then read all the xml as a whole text:

```
var xmlContent = File.ReadAllText("path");
```

Then replace the invalid chars using `LINQ` and [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee360286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var validContent = string.Concat(xmlContent
        .Select(x =>
        {
            if (invalidChars.Contains(x)) return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x);
            return x.ToString();
        }));
```

Then parse it using `XDocument.Parse`, that's all.