# SQL Server data type to replace XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqldatatypes

I store very large strings into SQL Server DB as XML data type. But this type has problems in storing certain characters. Is there another data type that can be used to store the data and not have problems with special characters?

Comment: You might have to escape xml special characters (like &), but it can store any character

Comment: Please define your special characters and the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: true, but is there a data type of the same size (2GB i think) that can be used?

Comment: What sort of *processing* of this data do you do on the SQL Server side?

Comment: already found the errors and corrected based on this replay [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048158/parsing-xml-which-contains-illegal-characters) but is there a similar data type size wise?

Comment: now I also found the letter é in there

Comment: Did you try varchar(max) ?

Comment: I'd rather go with nvarchar(max) because I'm afraid I will have problems with special characters and I'd rather avoid doing encoding conversions every time I read from or write to the database. Is this the way to go then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvarchar(max) is ok size wise and is Unicode to help with localized data. "max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying." [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)